# change SystemTray Color in whole application - windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, system-tray

I want to change the `SystemTray` Background and Foreground color in whole application but I don't define a base page and now I can't change the color for each page. is there a way for changing the background and foreground color of `SystemTray` in whole application through `App.xaml.cs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution for Windows phone RT app:
In OnLaunched method of App.xaml add below code:

```
     var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
     statusBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
     statusBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
     statusBar.BackgroundOpacity = 1;

     statusBar.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Some text";
     statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();
```

Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2014/05/12/status-bar-in-windows-phone-8-1.aspx

For WP Silverlight App:
You may need to define style in App.xaml under  tag

```
 <Style x:Key="SystemTrayStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
        <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
```

And on individual xaml page you can add this style

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
Style="{StaticResource SystemTrayStyle}">
```

Comment: my app in windows phone 8 silverlight app. is there a solution for wp8?